# How to read excel with custom format

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

i have a excel file with custom format like this
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIYfI.png)

can i read spesific column ex: "Double" with phpspreadsheet and convert to array ?

this is my code

```
public function readExcelData($fileName, $tmpName)
    {
        // get file extension
        $extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ($extension == 'csv') {
            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
        } elseif ($extension == 'xlsx') {
            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
        } else {
            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
        }
        // file path
        $reader->setLoadSheetsOnly(["Planning"]);
        $spreadSheet = $reader->load($tmpName);
        $sheetData = $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($sheetData); $i++) {
            $fetchData[] = array(
                'double' => $sheetData[$i]['Double']
            );
        }
        return $fetchData;
    }
```

Comment: after running the function, what did you get? any error or result?

Comment: `A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Filename: Calculation/Calculation.php

Line Number: 3465` , i get error like this @zimorok

Comment: What is at Line 3465? Most likely it encounter empty data